Decoding Gnosis Safe Transactions
we need to get the 'data' argument from a gnosis safe txn in our subgraph. The existing ethabi library fails to decode any gnosis safe txn, so we are unable to index certain function calls that come from a gnosis safe. What is the best way to do this within the context of subgraph development?

There is a dedicated API endpoint for decoding data that takes a data
and a to argument. If you don't have the data argument you can use another endpoint to first get this information.
Specifically in the context of TheGraph, this repo and subgraph index transactions for Safe multisigs up to version 1.3.0, hopefully it can provide you with an example on how to do so?
Hope it helps; Best, Louis
